# Github is rejecting my push because i adjusted something on the web version

Tags: bash, git, github, push, commit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKJq.jpg

I adjusted something on the Github repository from the web interface and also renamed a file from the local git stage. but I can't seem to push my commit to the web interface.

I added a screenshot of what I'm getting as a response

Comment: please don't add screenshots of text - just put the text :). Have you read what it says?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull the repository to your local machine **git pull** and then you can push **git push** the changes to remote repository. This might work.